# Annoying error on summer of nhibernate screencast

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I was trying to follow the summer of nhibernate screnncast series but I'm stuck at an early session. So this is the problem:

When I am trying to run the following method:

```
public void GetMyTestDataXMLFile()
{
    SaveTestDatabase();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    Test Report: file:///C:/Users/pina/AppData/Local/Temp/Gallio/TDNetRunner/Report/DataAccessLayerTest.dll.html
** NO TESTS WERE RUN (No tests found) **
Test 'M:DataAccessLayerTest.Tests.GetMyTestDataXMLFile' failed: SqlDbCommandBuilder.CreateSelectCommand(DataSet, string) failed for tableName = 'Customer'
    NDbUnit.Core.NDbUnitException: SqlDbCommandBuilder.CreateSelectCommand(DataSet, string) failed for tableName = 'Customer' ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
    at NDbUnit.Core.SqlClient.SqlDbCommandBuilder.getSchemaTable(SqlCommand sqlSelectCommand)
    at NDbUnit.Core.SqlClient.SqlDbCommandBuilder.CreateSelectCommand(DataSet ds, String tableName)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at NDbUnit.Core.SqlClient.SqlDbCommandBuilder.CreateSelectCommand(DataSet ds, String tableName)
    at NDbUnit.Core.DbCommandBuilder.BuildCommands(Stream xmlSchema)
    at NDbUnit.Core.NDbUnitTest.ReadXmlSchema(Stream xmlSchema)
    at NDbUnit.Core.NDbUnitTest.ReadXmlSchema(String xmlSchemaFile)
    at Microdesk.Utility.UnitTest.DatabaseUnitTestBase.SaveDatabase(String connectionString, String schemaFilePathName, String datasetFilePathName, DatabaseClientType clientType)
    at Microdesk.Utility.UnitTest.DatabaseUnitTestBase.SaveTestDatabase()
    TestClass1.cs(291,0): at DataAccessLayerTest.Tests.GetMyTestDataXMLFile()
```

The only difference is that I am using a local Database (.sdf file). I'm sure that it has to be related with the connection string but I can't seem fix this.

This is my app.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="testDatabase"
             connectionString="Data Source=H:\Code\NHibernateSample\DataAccessLayer\FirstSample.sdf"
             providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I am using VS 2010.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with NHibernate. NHibernate appears nowhere in the call stack. Appears to be a configuration relating purely to SqlServerCe.

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to figure it out. It appears that the Test Driven framework doesn't fully support to work with the .sdf files & the SQLServerCe. I've installed a new SQL Server local instance and created a new DB and everything was fixed.

Later on I'll post the new app.config file.